# Monitorar alterações no valor de um atributo JSON de uma URL

Tags: json, api

Gostaria de saber a forma com melhor custo/benefício para monitorar as alterações no valor de um atributo retornado por uma URL em formato JSON. Ou seja, tenho a URL de uma API que me retorna algo do tipo:

```
{"high": 340.0, "volume": 261.83}
```

E gostaria de criar um serviço para chamar esta URL de tempos e tempos e me notificar se o valor do atributo "high" atende a uma condição, seja maior ou menor que um valor x, por exemplo. Pode ser em qualquer linguagem. Alguém já criou algo assim?

Comment: Para melhorar o desempenho disso vai ter que aumentar o tempo entre as requisições, porem teu sistema vai ter uma precisão menor ao responder a alteração do valor.

Comment: Não entendi o comentário. Aumentar o tempo? Digamos que seja a cada 10min, qual sua sugestão de implementação?

Comment: Você pergunta sobre custo/beneficio. Beneficio: Precisão na resposta, custo: No desempenho ao requisitar constantemente o servidor. ou Beneficio: Baixo número de requisições e bom desempenho, custo: Baixa precisão. Me expressei mal no primeiro comentário, estava com pressa.

Comment: Sugestão de implementação? Depende, o que vai acontecer quando o valor mudar? Vai atualizar/criar algo no banco de dados? arquivo? acessar outro servidor? Ou vai simplesmente avisar o usuário?

Comment: Só notificar mesmo, por enquanto só gostaria de saber como monitorar a mudança. Eu sei que a reação ao monitoramento pode ajudar a definir a escolha final da linguagem mas queria sugestões de como algo deste tipo é feito por ai, devo criar uma app console e deixar executando ininterruptamente pegando os valores e testando a condição? Existe algum serviço gratuito como https://visualping.io ou algo assim? Outras linguagens como ruby, python ou o node.js podem fazer isso de forma fácil?